# How to capture depth photo with iphone x builtInTrueDepthCamera?

Tags: ios, depth, iphone-x

My goal is to get depth data from builtInTrueDepthCamera.
As a new bee, I tried apple's demo https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AVCamPhotoFilter/Listings/README_md.html

But this demo won't take depth photo as self.photoOutput.isDepthDataDeliverySupported is always false (This is not necessarily right). So I just wonder what should I do to get it work for me?

Any other demo is ok for me.

Thanks

Comment: Did you watch any of the WWDC 2017 videos about depth data?

Comment: No and I will! Thanks

Comment: I looked at that sample a week or two ago and found it hasn’t been updated for iPhone X / TrueDepth. Before you can set up depth delivery on the photo output, you’ll need to make sure that you’ve selected the builtInTrueDepthCamera capture device, and “out of the box” that sample only looks for builtInWideAngleCamera or builtInDualCamera. Did you have this problem after changing the part where it looks up camera devices, or have you not made that change?